# make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs

Tags: makefile, msys

I seem to get this error a lot and I find no resources online on how to actually do something about it.  This is all that it gives me.  Running Git for Windows newest version.

```
make-4.2$ make
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/bjwil/Downloads/make-4.2.tar/make-4.2'
make[1]: *** Error -1
.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry thought I added it in.  I am trying to configure packages.  I was trying to configure M4 package and was getting errors and wanted to update make and get same errors

Comment: try running make with `--debug=v`

Comment: i get the same thing except this time with `Main thread handle = 000000E0` after line `Entering directory`.  It actually just finished this time as well with the line `make: *** [Makefile:534: all] Error 130`

Answer (score 2):

It might help to use the `-k` flag. This forces `make` to continue even after encountering an error. I was having an issue with `make -j` where it would stop at the first error found, but the `-k` flag has it power through and continue anyways. It'll still display the error as normal, only it won't just give up at that point.

Answer (score 2):

"Waiting for unfinished jobs" is just informational, not an error message.  GNU `make` running in parallel mode emits that when one job encounters an error that requires `make` to terminate, to explain why the overall `make` hasn't yet stopped (though it will, possibly very quickly).  Although I don't see a `-j` flag on your command line to request parallel mode, perhaps `make` is taking one from environment variable `MAKEFLAGS`.

There isn't actually any real error message in your example, which is itself a clue.  Considering the main part of `make`'s output ...

> ```
> make-4.2$ make
> C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make  all-recursive
> make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/bjwil/Downloads/make-4.2.tar/make-4.2'
> make[1]: *** Error -1
> ```

... my first guess would be that `make` is unable to access folder `C:/Users/bjwil/Downloads/make-4.2.tar/make-4.2`.  Some possible reasons for that would be

- It's not a real folder.  The full path to it suggests that it might, instead, be a virtual folder view of the contents of a tar archive.
- It has been deleted out from under you, or its permissions have been changed such that they deny access.  The former is hard to achieve on Windows, but perhaps it's possible.

I would expect that you could get rid of the "waiting for unfinished jobs" bit by specifying `-j1` as a command-line option, but I would not expect that alone to make your build succeed.